# popup has no binding, reapplying clears entire viewmodel

Tags: templates, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/SRUKN/24/

I'm using this to create a new div:

```
$("<div/>", {
    class: "itemView",
    id: name,
    "data-bind": "template: { name: 'tmplItemView' }"
}).appendTo("body")
```

The template has the proper data-binds

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmplItemView">
    <div class="itemHeader" data-bind="text: name">Item Name</div>
    <span id="itemClose" class="closeWindow"><i class="icon-remove">X</i></span>
</script>
```

But when I trigger the creation, it creates an empty div in the DOM.  If I applybindings immediately afterwards, the template seems to work correctly (ie the DIV is not empty) but it clears the entire viewmodel.

I had dealt with this before, but I think the difference now is that I'm using a jquery function to catch the click instead of using knockout's click binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look and found a work around. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SRUKN/26/

```
function createItemDiv(item) {
    console.log('Creating div from template');
    var $el = $("<div/>", {
        class: "itemView",
        id: item.name(),
        "data-bind": "template: { name: 'tmplItemView' }"
    });
    $el.appendTo("body");
    $el.draggable();
    ko.applyBindings(item, $el.get(0));
}
```

Basically, I am just making sure that the `applyBindings` call is more targeted by passing both the VM to bind to, plus the targeted element.